# Caramel popcorn material

Tags: materials

[image][image]I am really struggling to figure out how to make a caramelized popcorn material. I tried using a noise texture and a mix of glossy shader and diffuse, also i played around with the principled shader, but it looks horrible. it looks nothing like caramelized popcorn. I feel that it should be straight forward and easy, but I clearly can't see the solution here. i would like it to be procedural, so that I can quickly have 3 or 4 different kernels that I can then make a lot more of.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your textures so far. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.

Comment: Also add reference images of the look you are trying to achieve